# Tax rate on miscellaneous income

Tags: united-states, taxes

Where would I find US tax rates on miscellaneous income that does not have an associated W2 or 1099?

For example, let's say I start mowing lawns for my neighbors and a make a few thousand dollars for that. I don't have a specific business or anything. From what I can tell, I'd have to file a 1040 schedule C, but I can't seem to find what tax rate I'd pay. Would it be the same as if it's a 1099, or is it taxed at a different rate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For example, let's say I start mowing lawns for my neighbors and a
>   make a few thousand dollars for that. I don't have a specific business
>   or anything.

To the IRS, you do have a business, which is why you'll file a Schedule C (Profit or Loss from Business). A 1099 is just a way for the IRS to track payments to businesses in certain situations, to make it harder to hide income. So yes, it will be the same as if it was business income reported on a 1099.

You'll report all of your business income and expenses on the Schedule C, and you'll be taxed on the profit. You'll pay self-employment tax at 15.3%, but half of that is deductible, and for income tax 80% of your business profit will flow into your 1040 and contribute to your total income before deductions. The income tax rate on your business income will depend on your total income and deductions.

Comment: Note that "self-employment tax" is just what you'd have withheld for Social Security &c if you were an employee.

Comment: @jamesqf: more correctly, the Self-Employment Tax is the FICA tax (Social Security tax and Medicare tax) that you would have paid as an employee *plus* the FICA tax that your employer would have paid if you were an employee.